# I pressed ctrl alt f1 and lost everything

Tags: 20.04

i pressed `ctrl` `alt` `f1`and my pc restarted and all my files were lost, i tried to navigate using `ctrl` `alt` `f1` to `f6` but I type my login and it does not enter the account. I'm going to lose all my files from before?

Comment: Start by backing your files up: if you can’t log in to your system, use a live usb session to access the files to back them up to an  external drive- then try to fix the problem.

Comment: When you press Ctrl-Alt-F1, you are usually only switching to login screen, the PC does not restart. Ctrl-Alt-F2 should return to the previous session. Are you sure this isn't the case?

Answer (score 2):

You did not loose anything. However, you landed on a GDM login screen.

Linux runs a number of virtual consoles, tty's. In Ubuntu, the login manager, GDM, runs on tty1. Your user session runs on tty2. tty3 to tty6 are unused text consoles. You can login to these and work in a console-only environment.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> keys allow to switch to another tty from within a graphical environment, i.e. when you are on tty2 (your user session) or tty1 (the login manager). When in a non graphical tty, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> will switch to a different tty. You can also move to the lower tty or to the higher tty with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right</kbd>.

In your case, hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> would have brought you back to your running programms in your user session.

It is hoped that this gives you a bit more understanding and avoid confusion when you accidentally hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or another of these combinations. This is a traditional linux thing, and while it is useful and powerful to have these different consoles, I agree that for new users, this facility may not bring the best of experiences.